# How can I communicate a guest VM to Host using Host-Only Adapter? (Virtual Box)

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

I'm trying to make a connection from a **guest virtual machine** (VM) to **host**. I can from **host** to the **guest VM**, but not viceversa.

The context:
I'm trying to gain root access on a CTF VM from VulnHub.com, and I configured the **guest VM** (the CTF VM) network to **Host-Only**. Instead, if I choose **Bridged Adapter**, it works normally, but it means the VM is connected "directly" to my physical network adapter, and I want to avoid that for security reasons.

Some other thing I read is set 2 adapter: **NAT** and **Host-Only**, but it gives me only the **NAT** ip address range (10.0.x.x).

Basically, I want to use netcat to make a connection sending a reverse shell from the **guest VM** to the **host**, but I want to make it work with the **Host-Only** Adapter, not **Bridged Adapter**. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was I xd

Why? Because I was trying to access from the **host-only** adapter (named vboxnet0 in my machine) to the **psysical** adapter (a switch router). The **host-only** is a configuration which isolates the networking between the host machine and the guest virtual machine.

So, the IP (**IPv4 address**) to communicate from guest to host was specified when I created **vboxnet0** on **Host Network Manager** (VirtualBox 6.1). And **IS NOT** the one I found using the command **ifconfig**  in Linux.

I hope this can help another newbie who have this misunderstanding.
(Pro-Tip: **Learn more about networking**)